# Failure to Modify Tables Contained in List When Calling in For-loops -> R/Rmarkdown

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to conduct a variety of operations on a list of tables. The tables were loaded in from a single excel file using the following method (note that the file directory and some variable names have been removed/changed for confidentiality, as this is for work). Each table is a sheet from the excel file.

```
### Automated approach to loading in multiple sheets with given file names


# 1) Use "excel_sheets()" to pull names of sheets from file

sheet_names <- excel_sheets(path = "my path")



# 2) Use "lapply()" with daughter function (specified in argument "FUN = ") of "read_excel" to repeatedly read each sheet for all sheets in the generated list of sheet names (called "sheet_names")

subsurf_list_data <- lapply(X = sheet_names, FUN = read_excel, path = "my path")



# 3) Custom renaming of sheets, and force into global environment using the "list2env()" function

subsurf_list <- c("table1", "table2", "table3", "table4", "table5", "table6")
names(subsurf_list_data) <- subsurf_list
list2env(subsurf_list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

This part *seems* to have worked because the details for `subsurf_list_data` (the list of tables I want to iterate over in for-loops) show it as a list of six elements with the correct variables as the elements. Each variable also calls to the correct table. However, when I try to iterate over that list (`subsurf_list_data`) nothing works. The for-loops aren't throwing errors, they just won't perform the operations that I want them too. This has happened with multiple different for-loops involving a variety of operations. This leads me to believe that it is an issue with the list of tables itself, rather than the tables (especially since the same operations work fine when done manually).

As a simple example, I wrote a for-loop to create a column with all entries equal to the boolean `T` but the loop doesn't do anything.

```
# Start by generating a new column called "detect_bool" with "T" as the default value.

for (i in 1:length(subsurf_list_data)) {
   dat <- subsurf_list_data[i]
   dat["detect_bool"] <- T
}
```

It's bizarre that this doesn't work because the only operation I'm doing in the loop (`dat["detect_bool"] <- T`) works when it's done manually on the elements (like `table3` for example). Also, if I separately call an element from the list using its index (IE: `subsurf_list_data[3]`) then I get the correct output (`table3`).

I'm really at a loss here. I have been unable to figure out why something as basic as calling variables from a list has had this problem. Doubly so since I have not received any errors when performing the operations/for-loops.

Please let me know if I need to provide any follow-up information.

**Attempted solutions:**

Approach 1: iterate over the elements in `subsurf_list_data` directly (`for (dat in subsurf_list_data)`)

Approach 2: iterate over indices in a vector of correct length (`for (i in 1:length(subsurf_list_data)) {... subsurf_list_data[i] ...}`).

Approach 3: chuck a brick at my computer.

Comment: `lapply(subsurf_list_data, FUN = function(x) dplyr::mutate(x, detect_bool = T))`

Comment: As an aside, I don't think using `list2env(some_list, .GlobalEnv)` is a good approach. It crowds your environment, making it easy to confuse yourself, and having your various data frames all in one list object allow you to do functional approaches like using `lapply()` or `purrr::map()` to iterate over a change you want to make across those data frames.